# Getting a local position of a transform movment

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform

Let's say I have object A nested in B.
I can get a local position of A in the coordination system of B by calling `A.transform.localPosition`.

If I move the object A using A.tranform.translate( new Vector3(0,1,0) ), the object A will move to its y position. In this case, how can I know this resulting local coordination of the object A in the coordination system of the object B ***before I actually move the object A***?

For example, let's say the local position of the object A nested in B was (20,3,4). Now I want to know what will be the local coordination of the object A if I run `A.transform.translate( new Vector3(0,30,0) )`.

Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't localPosition the difference between the parent's and child's position?

Comment: Yes it is. So, how do I know the result (local position) of the child after child.transform.translate( Vec.Y) has been performed, without actually perform it?

Comment: `Vector3 newLocalPos = B.transform.position - A.transform.position;` ?